# Trailing space when generating md5

Tags: openssl, hashsum

I apologize if this has already been answered, or if the answer is simpler than I realize, but I can't seem to figure out the following:

When I try to generate an md5 from a string, either with

```
echo -n "string" | md5sum | cut -f1 -d' '
```

or with

```
echo -n "string" | openssl md5
```

the result is not 32 characters, as I would expect, but rather 33 (using `wc -c`).

So, I have a few questions:

1. Why do both md5sum and openssl add a trailing space?
2. Is there another way to generate an md5 hash without a trailing newline or space?
3. Does the trailing space really matter?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Instead of using awk like in the answer below i would use `tr` like this: `echo -n "string" | md5sum | cut -d " " -f 1 | tr -d "\n" `. This will clear the new line character from the output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's 32 characters! The `md5sum` is adding a linefeed to the end. You can get rid of it like this:

```
% echo -n string | md5sum|awk '{print $1}'|wc -c
33
% echo -n $(echo -n string | md5sum|awk '{print $1}')|wc -c
32
```

or you could do it like this:

```
% echo -n $(md5sum <<< 'string'|awk '{print $1}')|wc -c
32
```

You can tell when one of the commands is adding a newline because the 32 character string will show up on its own line. If no newline is present it should always show up like this:

```
[prompt %] echo -n $(md5sum <<< 'string'|awk '{print $1}')
b80fa55b1234f1935cea559d9efbc39a[prompt %]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation to vote you up. For the sake of clarity though, I think I like `echo -n $(echo -n "string" | openssl md5)`

Comment: Sure! That's the beauty of UNIX. There's more than one way to do everything!